# when to use callbacks in ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

why use the first method and the call to it. (call back functions).  and why not use the last one? http://pastebin.ca/2683261

one method is using `success: success`    line 8 . and the caller of that method actually puts up the method on success (line 16)

someone told me that the last method wont do anything since the reply from server (success/failure) would `come late`r. and I need to use the `callbacks` like the first method

**I did remember that I got an issue with traditional one. I just cant remember what it was. I think some thing that I didnt got the response when it was intended to. Some one told me that you wont get the response right away as its async. you need call backs. he was correct. But I dont remember the use case
**

**with `success:success` (callback at method call)**

```
function ajaxEditBox(box, boxType, boxTitle, boxDescription, success, error){
    var boxId = box.attr('id').split("-")[1];
    alert("box id to be sent to edit by ajax call: "+boxId +" type:"+boxType+" title:"+boxTitle+" desc"+boxDescription);

    $.ajax({
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/box/edit/"+boxId+"/"+boxType+"/"+boxTitle+"/"+boxDescription,
        cache: false,
        success: success,
        error: error
    });
}
```

**callback at method call**

```
 ajaxEditBox(window.box, boxType, boxTitle, boxDescription, function(){
            alert("boo");
            $(window.box).removeClass("box-vertical");
            $(window.box).removeClass("box-horizontal");
            $(window.box).addClass("box-"+boxType);
            $(window.box).find(".box-title-text").first().html(boxTitle);
                    //description change/edit is pending.


        },
        function(){
            alert("ooh");
        });
```

**traditional ajax**

```
function ajaxCreateBox(parent){

$.ajax({

        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/box/create/"+parentType+"/"+parentId+"/"+boxType+"/"+boxTitle+"/"+boxDescription,
        cache: false,
        //data:'firstName=' + $("#firstName").val() + "&lastName=" + $("#lastName").val() + "&email=" + $("#email").val(),
        success: function(response){

            $('#result').html(fetchedBoxId+" "+fetchedBoxType+" "+fetchedBoxTitle+" "+fetchedBoxDescription);
            // createBoxInDom();
            $("#"+parentElementId+" > ."+parentType+"-body").append(
                    '<div id="boxid-'+fetchedBoxId+'" class="box box-'+fetchedBoxType+'" >'+
                            '    <div class="box-title" title="'+fetchedBoxDescription+'">'+
                         ...
..
..
..
some logic
...
..
                            '        <div class="box-body">'+
                            '        </div>   '+
                            '</div>');



        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error while request..');
        }
```

Comment: It makes your code more flexible. You can use the same Ajax call and process the response differently by providing different callbacks. If you don't need want that, use the last one. *"someone told me that the last method wont do anything since the reply from server (success/failure) would come later. and I need to use the callbacks like the first method"* That has nothing to do with the code you posted. The difference is that the last way uses a "fixed" success callback and the first one uses whatever is passed into the function.

Comment: I did remember that I got an issue with traditional one. I just cant remember what it was. I think some thing that I didnt got the response when it was intended to.

Comment: It's difficult for me to comment on something that you can't really remember. As I said, both solutions use callbacks. The first just lets the caller of `ajaxEditBox` defined the callback, whereas the last one always uses the same callback.

Comment: Some one told me that you wont get the response right away as its async. you need call backs. he was correct. But I dont remember the use case

Comment: Again, both solutions use callbacks. A callback is just a function passes to another function. And yes, when you are working with Ajax, you have to use callbacks. And that's what you do in both cases. Your whole premise is wrong: Both solutions are essentially the same. The first one is just a bit more flexible.

Comment: does it has to do anything with DOM manipulation or delayed thing